# Using Pandas how to use next step analysis for getting data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data :

```
Village     Workers       Level
Aagar       10            Small
Dhagewadi   32            Small
Sherewadi   34            Small
Shindwad    42            Small
Dhokari     84            Medium
Khanapur    65            Medium
Ambikanagar 45            Medium
Takali      127           Large
Gardhani    122           Large
Pi.Khand    120           Large
Pangri      105           Large
```

Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("/home/desktop/Desktop/t.csv")
df = df.sort('Workers', ascending=False)           
df['Level'] = pd.qcut(df['Workers'], 3, ['Small','Medium','Large'])
df['Sum_Level_wise'] = df.groupby('Level')['Workers'].transform('sum')
df['Probability'] = df['Sum_Level_wise'].div(df['Workers'].sum()).round(2)
df['Sample'] = df['Probability'] * df.groupby('Level')['Workers'].transform('size')
df['Selected villages'] = df['Sample'].apply(np.ceil).astype(int)


def f(x):
    a = x['Village'].head(x['Selected villages'].iat[0])
    print (x['Village'])
    print (a)
    if (len(x) < len(a)):
        print ('original village cannot be filled to Selected village, because length is higher')
    return a

df['Selected village'] = df.groupby('Level').apply(f).reset_index(level=0)['Village']
df['Selected village'] = df['Selected village'].fillna('')

print (df)
```

Next, I have get villages which was selected in sampling

[image]

So, I just want to selected village name  corresponding  workers details and Level column only.

like this :( Excel photo )

[image]

So,I just want that village name, because  I dont want to show each steps.

Just using sampling that 5 villages are comes, that data will be show, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you need [head](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
result_df= df.head(n=5)
result_df
```

`result_df` will be:

```
    Village   Workers Level Sum_Level_wise Probability Sample Selected villages Selected village
7   Takali    127     Large  474           0.60        2.40   3                 Takali
8   Gardhani  122     Large  474           0.60        2.40   3                 Gardhani
9   Pi.Khand  120     Large  474           0.60        2.40   3                 Pi.Khand
10  Pangri    105     Large  474           0.60        2.40   3 
4   Dhokari   84      Medium 194           0.25        0.75   1                 Dhokari
```

If you need just columns 'Village','Workers' and 'Level', then try with:

```
result_df[['Village','Workers','Level']]
```

It will give you:

```
    Village     Workers Level
7   Takali      127     Large
8   Gardhani    122     Large
9   Pi.Khand    120     Large
10  Pangri      105     Large
4   Dhokari     84      Medium
```

**Update:**

```
df['Selected village'].replace('', pd.np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset=['Selected village'], inplace=True)
df[['Workers','Level','Selected village']]
```

it will give:

```
    Workers Level   Selected village
0   10      Small   Aagar
4   84      Medium  Dhokari
7   127     Large   Takali
8   122     Large   Gardhani
9   120     Large   Pi.Khand
```

Comment: I want village name which is created df['selected village']  only.  not head(n) we can use here .   for example :  in my question there are 5 villages are comes in the last column --> selected village column , there are 5 villages 1) Takali 2) Gardhani 3) Pi.Khand 4) Dokari 5)Shindwad are selected .. so, I just want this 5 village name with  number of workers column and level corresponding that village